How can I fix the 'Unexpected tokens' error when enabling ViewBinding in build.gradle?
I'm trying to add the ViewBinding feature in the app's build.gradle file as per the official Android documentation, but I'm not getting the desired output. Instead, I'm encountering the error "Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)." Please correct this issue.
This is what i have entered:
buildFeatures {
   viewBinding true
} 

I have tried this also :
buildFeatures {
   viewBinding = true
}

but not able to access the binding in the main activity.
